# Can't make Doubly Linked List work

Tags: java

So my homework assignment is:
(Doubly-Linked Lists) Implement a doubly-linked list holding integer values. Populate the list with the values [ 11, 22, 77, 44,55,66, 33 ]. Show the contents of the list. Write a method to separate the value into odd first, even later. In our example the reordered list should be: [ 11, 77, 55, 33, 22, 44, 66 ].

I can get it to work and do what its supposed to for up to 6 numbers, but adding the 7th number it errors out.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MyList.sortData(MyList.java:100)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:24)



public class Driver {

       /**
        * @param args
        */
       public static void main(String[] args) {

          MyList<Integer> list = new MyList<Integer>();
          list.add(11);
          list.add(22);
          list.add(77);
          list.add(44);
          list.add(55);
          list.add(66);
          list.add(33);

          System.out.println("<<Original Data>>");
          list.showData();
          System.out.println();

          System.out.println("<<Sorted Data>>");
          list.sortData(list);
          list.showData();

       }

    }





public class MyList<E>{

   private Node<E> head;
   private Node<E> tail;
   int count;

   public MyList(){
      head = null;
      tail = null;
      count = 0;
   }

   public Node<E> add(E newData){
      Node<E> current = new Node<E>(newData);

      // case 1: list is empty
      if (count == 0){
         count ++;
         head = current;
         tail = current;
         return current;
      }

      // case 2: list is not empty
      if (count > 0){
         count ++;
         tail.setNext(current);
         current.setPrior(tail);
         tail = current;

         return current;
      }
      return null;
   }

   public Node<E> removeFirst(){
      Node<E> firstNode = head;

      if (head == tail){
         count = 0;
         head = tail = null;
         return firstNode;
      }
      else{
         head = firstNode.getNext();
         count --;
         return firstNode;
      }
   }

   public Node<E> removeLast(){
      Node<E> lastNode = tail;
      Node<E> current = head;

      if (head == tail){
         count = 0;
         head = tail = null;
         return lastNode;
      }
      else{
         count --;
         tail = tail.getPrior();
         tail.setNext(null);
         return lastNode;
      }  
   }

   public Node<E> removeAt(int index){
      Node<E> current = head;
      Node<E> next = null;
      Node<E> prior = null;

      if (index > count) return null;
      if (index == 0) return removeFirst();
      if (index == count -1) return removeLast();

      else{
         for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
            current = current.getNext();
         }

         next = current.getNext();
         prior = current.getPrior();
         prior.setNext(next);
         next.setPrior(prior);
         count--;
         return next;  
      }
   }

   public void sortData(MyList<Integer> list){
      Node<E> current = head;
      int key = 0;

      while(count > 0){
         Node<E> data =  current;

         if((Integer)current.getData() % 2 == 0){
            current = (Node<E>) list.removeAt(key);
            list.add((Integer)data.getData());
         }

         else{
            key++;
            current = current.getNext();
         }

         count--;        
      }
   }

   public void showData(){
      Node<E> current = head;
        System.out.print("[");
      while(current != null){
         System.out.println(current.showData());
         current = current.getNext();
      }

        System.out.print("]");
   }
}



    public class Node<E> implements Comparable<E>{
   private E data;
   private Node<E> next;      
   private Node<E> prior;

   public Node(E newElement){
      data = newElement;
      next = null;
      prior = null;

   }

   public Node<E> getPrior() {
      return prior;
   }

   public void setPrior(Node<E> prior) {
      this.prior = prior;
   }

   public E getData() {
      return data;
   }

   public void setData(E data) {
      this.data = data;
   }

   public Node<E> getNext() {
      return next;
   }

   public void setNext(Node<E> next) {
      this.next = next;
   }

   public String showData(){
      String result = " " + data +" ";
      return result;
   }

   @Override
   public int compareTo(E otherData) {
      String thisData = (String) data;
      if (thisData.compareTo((String)otherData) == 0)
         return 0;
      else if  (thisData.compareTo((String)otherData) < 0)
         return -1;
      else
         return 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? The asker admitted it's homework, provided code, and gave a concrete problem. It looks like a good faith effort, and they didn't ask to be handed an answer. Downvotes for effort discourage people from asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

I usually don't even read questions about homework mainly because the questions are "How to implement...". But made exception and I think your effort deserve some hint.

Look at the "count" member field. You have few functions that rely on it being correct where one of your functions is trashing it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I've gone over it, and everything is as it should be as far as I can see with count.  Its initialized, increases where it needs, and decreases where it needs.  I don't see where its getting "trashed" so to speak.  Ill just have to ask my professor tomorrow.  Thanks for the effort =)

Comment: An extra hint, then: Think carefully about what you want your sortData() function to do. What should the values of your list be after it exits?

Comment: _(Both of the hints are very well done:  Helpful direction for the student.)_